# registerForRemoteNotification is not working in .mm file

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to write this pience of code in my app delegate class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    [FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"F9W2NQPF4Y587SM2Z3XU"];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [window addSubview:OCRScreen.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [OCRScreen displayScreen];
    [OCRScreen.view removeFromSuperview];

    return YES;
}
```

but it's giving me error following error on first line.
OCRAppDelegate.mm: error: Semantic Issue: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIRemoteNotificationType' with an rvalue of type 'int'

when i change .mm to .m then it doesn't gives this error.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the first line of code to this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

now it will work.